# jQuery select and unselect image

Tags: jquery

i have image set div tag like below

```
<div style="width: 600px; background: #CCC;padding: 50px;" class="jjj">
<img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg" class="ddd"  width="200"/>
<img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg" class="ddd"  width="200"/>
<img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg" class="ddd"  width="200"/>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
<style>
.ddd:hover{
            transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(1.2); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(1.2); /* Firefox */
        }

        .selectedd{
            transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(1.2); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(1.2); /* Firefox */
border:2px inset silver;
        }
</style>
```

i need to select image when user click on it (change the class), i added the script for this and it working, but how can i deselect this image when user clicks on out side, i mean on div tag.
my jQuery

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.ddd').click(function(){
        ff=this;
        $('.ddd').removeClass('selectedd')
        $(ff).addClass('selectedd')
    }); 
    });
</script>
```

Please help me.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation()` when user clicks over an image, otherwise capture the click event on the body (or other element) and remove the `selectedd` class on the image (if any)

```
$(function(){
    var ff;

    $('.ddd').on('click', function(evt) {
        ff = $(this);
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $('.ddd').removeClass('selectedd')
        ff.addClass('selectedd')
    }); 
    $('body').on('click', function() {
        if (ff.length) {
           ff.removeClass('selectedd')
        }
    });
});
```